# wget how to use ganerated name instaed of page name when downolad zip file

Tags: php, wget, cpanel

I would like save few important data form a server(A) to another server(B) hourly .
I wrote a php script which compress all data into one zip file and generate name from current date time (A).

I want download this file from cpanel/cron with wget (B).

But the wget do not get the archive name just  if my site domain.com/arcive.php
The downloaded name will be archive.php instead of 2014050120112.zip.

B server do not know the name of archive.

Is there any way to wget accept the file generated file name?
(header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's there in the man pages too!

Use the `--content-disposition` option.